# Can't mount application.yaml into docker java 8 spring

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose, configuration

Can someone explain me, why it doesn't mounted and java don't read application.yaml?

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY build/libs/Notify-2.0-all.jar app.jar
COPY src/main/resources/application.yaml resources/application.yaml
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

and this is docker compose

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  discord-bot-cyberdawn-boosty:
    image: discord-bot-v2
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./application.yaml
        target: /app/resources/application.yaml
```

I tried `${pwd}` but it still doesn't work.

I also tried this

```
FROM openjdk:17
WORKDIR /app
COPY build/libs/Notify-2.0-all.jar app.jar
COPY src/main/resources/application.yaml /app/application.yaml
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar", "--spring.config.name=application", "--spring.config.location=file:/app/application.yaml"]
```

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  test-bot:
    image: test-bot-v2
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ${PWD}/application.yaml
        target: /app/application.yaml
```

and it's still doesn't work.

This doesn't work too:

```
docker run -v /home/bot-v2/cyberdawn/application.yaml:/app/application.yaml test-bot-v2
```

Comment: Try to use the absolute path instead of relative for `source`.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis i also try this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Jar file cant read application.yaml. I should use war.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you please elaborate further on what you mean?

Comment: @AlexandrosMaltezos jar application don’t support custom context. How I understand, jar support env variable’s